# Improving efficiency on background log routine

Tags: excel, vba

I created a log routine that creates a module in the desired file that records all changes for future auditing based on workbook events. I would like to com up with an alternative that I can activate at the start of a long process of routines applied to 100.000 rows, which mine doesn't seem to be able to support.

My log routine seems to work fine when activated in a blank worksheet, however it can't record all the changes made by my series of soubroutines. As it keeps track of each individual cell change in value and there are series of changes over the 100.000 rows, it crashes the application. I have been trying to think of a way to adapt it to be more efficient for my use, but so far I have been out of my depth.

Below is the code I import into the processed file to keep track of changes. If deemed necessary I can also post the routine that imports it.

```
public strOldAddress As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
Dim rngSubTarget As Range
Dim lngBothCounter As Long
Dim Post() As String

'\ Parameters to register changes
Dim wsLog As Worksheet
Dim lngLogInputRow As Long
Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")


'\ Detect changes in value
lngBothCounter = 1
ReDim Post(1 To Target.Cells.Count)
For Each rngSubTarget In Target.Cells
    '\ Error Handler for changed values
    If IsError(rngSubTarget.Value) Then
        Post(lngBothCounter) = "ERROR"
    Else
        Post(lngBothCounter) = rngSubTarget.Value
    End If
    '\ Debug.Print for each value Ante and Post
    'Debug.Print Post(lngBothCounter); " e " & Ante(lngBothCounter)
    '\ Add changes values to log
    If Ante(lngBothCounter) <> Post(lngBothCounter) Then
        rngSubTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        lngLogInputRow = wsLog.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 1).Value = wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 1).Row - 1
        wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 2).Value = Ante(lngBothCounter)
        wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 3).Value = Post(lngBothCounter)
        wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 4).Value = " " & rngSubTarget.Formula
        wsLog.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 5), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "'!" & rngSubTarget.Address, TextToDisplay:=rngSubTarget.Address
        wsLog.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 6), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "'!" & strOldAddress, TextToDisplay:=strOldAddress
        wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 7).Value = Environ("username")
        wsLog.Cells(lngLogInputRow, 8).Value = Now

    End If
    lngBothCounter = lngBothCounter + 1
Next rngSubTarget

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngSubTarget As Range
Dim lngAnteCounter As Long

lngAnteCounter = 1
ReDim Ante(1 To Target.Cells.Count)
For Each rngSubTarget In Target.Cells
    '\ Error Handling for values in selection
    If IsError(rngSubTarget.Value) Then
        Ante(lngAnteCounter) = "ERROR"
    Else
        Ante(lngAnteCounter) = rngSubTarget.Value
    End If
    lngAnteCounter = lngAnteCounter + 1
Next rngSubTarget

strOldAddress = Target.Address

End Sub
```

I expected it to keep track of all changes but when too many modifications are made through a macro it crashes the application (the log file is blank until I try to save the file, when it crashes).

Comment: I'll be honest, reading that you have 100,000 rows is a bit of a red flag. I'm not sure Excel is the right application for this, if you're trying to track the changes that happen over 100K rows.

Comment: @BigBen Is right. As much I love `Excel`, It is not the appropriate platform for logging changes to data of that size. Making numerous calls to the `Worksheet_Change` event to track changes on that much data is guaranteed to crash Excel. You should check out `Access`. You can create a log table that does exactly what you are talking about and it won't crash the application.

Comment: If you're making changes via a macro then why not log the changes there?

Comment: I'm sorry @TimWilliams, I'm not quite sure I get what you mean, could you please expand how would I log changes in the macro?

Comment: I mean that if you're updating cells you can look at the current value and log it before you make any changes

Comment: @TimWilliams I assume that's what I am doing, only that I am doing so through worksheet events and loging stuff into a separate sheet. Do you mean log stuff into an array, for example? If not, could you please provide a little more insight?

Comment: If you have a huge dataset and are making systematic changes (ie. not "random" manual changes) then why keep a log at all?  Make a copy of the original data and then any changes can be generated by comparing the initial and final versions.  That would avoid the need to slow down (or crash) your update macros with event-driven logging (not to mention your code performing a bunch of unnecessary `Select`'s)